# Creating JSON output file in C#

Tags: c#, android, json

How can I expose the data in json format ..??? I tried creating a JSON string using C# code in an aspx file and outputting it. For example, On opening default.aspx on browser , it out puts only json string. But I can't use the default.aspx link while processing in android sdk as the http response will include html tags also.

Basically if I select view source when I open the dafault.aspx, I can see html tags not just the JSON string. when I open json api for twitter,google calender and select view source they does not contain html. Can anyone help me create only json out put ...??? I have data in sql server and  quite good at C# coding.

Thanks in advance ....!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization; 

public class Person
{
   public string firstName = "bp";
   public string lastName = "581";
}

public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
   { 
      Person p = new Person();
      string output = JavaScriptObjectSerializer.Serialize(p);
      Response.Write(output);
      Response.Flush();
      Response.End();
   }          
 }
```

This is the aspx code behind example. The aspx file gets ignored after Response.End(). Or do it in an ashx file and forgo htmlpage markup.

Or even better, consider using a web service. WCF or an asmx .

Comment: I am getting this erro..The name 'JavaScriptObjectSerializer' does not exist in the current context. It works for normal json string..not for the example you provided.

Comment: This worked.. System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer =
         new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

        string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(p);

        Response.Write(sJSON);
       Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

Answer (score 0):

You should make an [ASHX handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not clearing the content before writing out the JSON string. It is much easier to do this in a "generic handler", i.e. an ashx file. Implement the ProcessRequest method, set the content type to "application/json", and write out your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to return C# object.

```
public JsonResult GetPerson()
{
   var p = new Person();
   p.FirstName = "Name";
   p.LastName = "LastName";
   return Json(p);
}
```

So you will get:

```
{
   "FirstName" : "Name",
   "LastName" : "LastName"
}
```